# Clipboard in nomachine stopped working after upgrade to 5.1.62

Tags: clipboard, nomachine

I have recently update the nomachine client to 5.1.62 on my Windows 7 box and the seamless clipboard synchronization between remote clipboard and local clipboard stopped working.

The clipboard works correctly if I run a session with complete desktop (gnome or kde). But when I run a custom session (xterm only) I am able to copy data to nomachine but the copying data from nomachine does not work. It neither work copying data between nomachine applications although it is possible to copy/paste inside one application.

So my questions are

Is there a workaround how to solve it?
Or is it possible to get older version of the nomachine client so I can downgrade to a version with working clipboard?
And is there a possibility to report the bug to NoMachine although I am not a registered (paying) user?

Comment: In the meanwhile I have found https://www.nomachine.com/report-issues and reported the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nomachine support admitted it is a defect. The bug does not occur when a newest nomachine server is used.

The defect can be tracked at https://www.nomachine.com/TR02O07562.